# Shiny Leaflet Hiding a conditional panel with a mouse click event

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to create a plot in the absolutePanel, using a conditionalPanel, that only appears when i click the mouse on the basemap. This is no problem and i've achieved that.

But i'd like the plot to clear and the conditionalPanel to collapse again once the user crosses off the point pop-up. At the moment the plot changes and replots data when another click is performed but it is the clearing of the pop-up that I would like linked to the collapsing of the conditionalPanel;

This very simple example shows the creation of the conditionalPanel upon click (the full version creates a point and reads a raster stack to plot a timeline):

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="100%"),
  absolutePanel(class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,draggable = TRUE,
                top = 20, left = 60,

                conditionalPanel("input.map_click",
                   h4(textOutput("Click_text")),
                top=20, left=60, height=400, width=200,
                style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(-4,52.5,9) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)  
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    text<-paste("Lattitude ", click$lat, "Longtitude ", click$lng)
    text2 <- paste("YOUVE CLICKED THE MAP!!!",click$lat, click$lng)

    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    proxy %>% clearPopups() %>%
      addPopups(click$lng, click$lat, text)

    output$Click_text<-renderText({text2})
  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

There is a suggestion [in the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) that there is an event called mouseout but it might just be linked to clicks on actual markers, as opposed to the maptile clicks, as i certainly couldnt get it to work. Any way to make the panel disappear after crossing off the pop-up?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/183) link popupclose event it doesn't seem to be implemented in shiny.

Comment: thanks for the link, i'd be wary of taking something from 2015 to still be the case for Shiny in R as i know 2016 moved on great leaps, but thanks for flagging it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems indeed that the `popup_close` event is still not implemented in `leaflet` for R.

Nonetheless we can build it using the awesome `htmlwidgets` package.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
```

We will use some `javascript` to:

- listen to the `popupclose` & `popupopen` events.
- send the information that the events happened to `Shiny`.

This can all be accomplished inside the `onRender()` function:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            setView(-4,52.5,9) %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 

            onRender("
                     function(el, x) {
                         this.on('popupopen', function(e) {
                             Shiny.onInputChange('myEvent', 'open');
                         });

                         this.on('popupclose', function(e) {
                             Shiny.onInputChange('myEvent', 'close');
                         });
                     }")
    })
```

`onRender()` adds some javascript code to be executed once the map is rendered.
In this case `this.on('popupopen', function())` create the event listener, while `Shiny.onInputChange('myEvent', 'close')` assigns the value `close` to   `input$myEvent`.

We now only need to change the condition for the panel:

```
 conditionalPanel("input.myEvent == 'open'", ...)
```

Comment: this is great thanks, works perfectly for a click event. Now I am trying to incorporate the drawToolbar functions from leaflet.extras, particularly the DELETESTOP listener, to delete graphs when deleting a drawn shape.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.